Whatsapp Business Api Template Message not working
WhatsApp Business Cloud API: Message Accepted but Not Delivered
I’m using the WhatsApp Business Cloud API to send a template message. The API request returns a status of "accepted," but the recipient is not receiving the message.
Request Details:

Request URL:
POST https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/<phone_number_id>/messages


Request Body:
{
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
    "recipient_type": "individual",
    "to": "<Mobile Number>",
    "type": "template",
    "template": {
        "name": "booking_details",
        "language": {
            "code": "en"
        },
        "components": [
            {
                "type": "body",
                "parameters": [
                    {"type": "text", "text": "chennai"},
                    {"type": "text", "text": "salem"},
                    {"type": "text", "text": "tn15505"},
                    {"type": "text", "text": "star"},
                    {"type": "text", "text": "23.02.2024"},
                    {"type": "text", "text": "koyambedu"},
                    {"type": "text", "text": "bus stand"},
                    {"type": "text", "text": "10:00 a.m."},
                    {"type": "text", "text": "₹5055"},
                    {"type": "text", "text": "L1/S,L2/S"}
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "button",
                "sub_type": "quick_reply",
                "index": "0",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "type": "payload",
                        "payload": "PAYNOW_PAYLOAD"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "button",
                "sub_type": "quick_reply",
                "index": "1",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "type": "payload",
                        "payload": "CHANGE_DETAILS_PAYLOAD"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}



Response:
{
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
    "contacts": [
        {
            "input": "receiver",
            "wa_id": "id"
        }
    ],
    "messages": [
        {
            "id": "wamid.HBgMOTE4MDU2MTg1NjI5FQIAERgSMUQwQzU3MjVENDBBMEQ5NTk5AA==",
            "message_status": "accepted"
        }
    ]
}

What I've Tried:

Verified that the template is approved and matches the template ID.
Confirmed the recipient's phone number is registered with WhatsApp.
Ensured the phone_number_id and access token are correct.
Checked that the recipient has opted in to receive messages.
Verified there's no issue with my WhatsApp Business Account (no low-quality rating or rate limiting).

Despite the message being accepted, it’s not delivered to the recipient. What could be the reasons for this, and how can I troubleshoot or resolve this issue?

You will always receive the web-hook , in this u can can check the reason for the message not receiving .
You can compare your response's messaage.id with webhook's response inside statuses array

if you received the template but not receiving the message then try to replay from that number to the number from which you are sending template . As whatsapp will not send message until user initiate chat in 24 hour timeline

Check the official document, it says it is in review(held_for_quality_assessment).
